# Filtro com angular em data com máscara 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'

Tags: angularjs

Estou aplicando um filtro na minha página, ele estava funcionando perfeitamente, só que quando apliquei a máscara para ficar no formato *dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss* ele parou de filtrar corretamente, ele entende que não existe nada correspondente, a partir do primeiro número digitado ele não consegue encontrar nada, volta vazia a lista, como se não existisse. Antes de aplicar o mascara, se eu digitava manualmente o dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss(digitando com os numeros e as separações / e :) ele encontrava perfeitamente o correspondente.
Os outros campos continuam filtrando corretamente.

```
    <div class="form-group filtro">
      <label class="" for="endDate">Data de Criação</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="criterioDeBusca.dataCriacao" ui-mask="99/99/9999 99:99:99" ui-mask-placeholder ui-mask-placeholder-char="_" />                         
   </div>
```

-

```
 <table>
     <tr dir-paginate="atividade in atividades | filter:criterioDeBusca | orderBy:criterioDeOrdenacao:direcaoDaOrdenacao|itemsPerPage:5">
      <td>{{atividade.codigo}}</td>
      <td class="text-left">{{atividade.descricao}}</td>
      <td>{{atividade.dataCriacao | date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: tente adicionar model-view-value="true", junto ao ui-mask, pode ser que manter o modelo de objeto resolva

Comment: Funcionou!! só que quando eu apago e digito novamente ele volta pro mesmo erro, ele entende que não existe nada, sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: nossa, pior que não faço idéia, geralmente procuro fazer filtros manualmente pelos filters e mascaras por diretivas, se quizer posto minha solução mas é totalmente diferente

Comment: @FelipeDuarte aceito sua solução sim, pode postar?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic ele vem como dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss

Comment: @VirgilioNovic nossa, vc imagina uma possivel solução?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu trocaria o ui-Mask pelo [`Mask Plugin`](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) pelo motivo da perca do formato no `model`, ***exemplo minimo***:

Para aplicar filtro em data e hora seria da seguinte forma:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#text').mask('00/00/0000 00:00:00');
});

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.text = "";
  $scope.datas = [{
      'id': 1,
      'data': '01/01/1999 13:45:55'
    },
    {
      'id': 2,
      'data': '01/01/1999 13:45:55'
    },
    {
      'id': 3,
      'data': '02/01/1999 14:46:00'
    },
    {
      'id': 4,
      'data': '03/01/1999 14:46:00'
    }
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="text" id="text" name="text" ng-model="text" />
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="d in datas | filter:text">
      <td>{{d.id}}</td>
      <td>{{d.data | date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui já é um bom caminho, pena que não estou com muito tempo agora :(

```js
angular.module('teste', []);

angular.module('teste').controller('testeCtrl' , function($scope){
 $scope.contatos = [];
  
  $scope.add = function(el){
   $scope.contatos.push(el);
  }
});

angular.module("teste").directive("uiDate", function ($filter) {
 return {
  require: "ngModel",
  link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
   var _formatDate = function (date) {
    if (!date) return date;
    date = date.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "");
    if(date.length > 2) {
     date = date.substring(0,2) + "/" + date.substring(2);
    }
    if(date.length > 5) {
     date = date.substring(0,5) + "/" + date.substring(5,9);
    }
    return date;
   };

   element.bind("keyup", function () {
    ctrl.$setViewValue(_formatDate(ctrl.$viewValue));
    ctrl.$render();
   });

   ctrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
    if (value.length === 10) {
     var dateArray = value.split("/");
     return new Date(dateArray[2], dateArray[1]-1, dateArray[0]).getTime();
    }
   });

   ctrl.$formatters.push(function (value) {
    return $filter("date")(value, "dd/MM/yyyy");
   });
  }
 };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="teste" ng-controller="testeCtrl">

<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="contato.data" name="data" placeholder="Data" ui-date/>

<tr ng-repeat="contato in contatos | filter:criterioDeBusca | orderBy:criterioDeOrdenacao:direcaoDaOrdenacao track by contato.id">
   <td>{{::contato.data | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
  </tr>
    

</body>
```

Comment: Muito obrigada pelo seu exemplo, mas aplicar o filtro com a dd/MM/yyyy eu havia conseguido, meu problema é quando é dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss

Comment: entendi, desculpa entendi mal kk