# Filtro pesquisa combobox AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Tenho o `SELECT` `multiple` com as opções para consulta, só que quando seleciono um item não retorna nada, se alguém puder dar uma força eu agradeço.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
/* Retorna operadoras */
$scope.operadoras = [{
    nome: "CLARO"
  },
  {
    nome: "TIM"
  },
  {
    nome: "VIVO"
  },
  {
    nome: "OI"
  },
  {
    nome: "NEXTEL"
  }
];

$scope.filtroOperadora = function() {
  return ($scope.operadoras == busca.nome);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-2 input-group-sm mb-3">
  <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="text-sm font-weight-bold">Operadora</label>
  <select class="form-control seleciona text-sm" multiple name="prospectOperadora" data-width="100%" ng-model="busca">
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
    <option ng-repeat="oper in operadoras" value="{{oper.nome}}">
      {{oper.nome}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>

<li style="font-size: 13px; padding:10px;" ng-repeat="prospect in listaProspect | orderBy: 'prospectNome' | betweenDate:'prospeccaoPrevisao':startDate:endDate | filter:busca track by $index">
</li>
```

Comment: Tem como colocar todo o código angular na sua pergunta? isso representa o seu exemplo minimo é fica complicado a gente fazer o código que com certeza já existe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo código informado, não é possível concluir muita coisa.

Porém, pelo que você colocou aqui:

```
$scope.filtroOperadora = function() {
  return ($scope.operadoras == busca.nome);
}
```

Não faz muito sentido, uma vez que o **$scope.operadoras** é um Array e **busca.nome** provavelmente é uma string.

Fiz um exemplo básico aqui:
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/Q1pKm1iN0P102c23

Porém, como provavelmente você pode ter um Array de strings quer buscar dentro da lista de operadoras, vai outro exemplo:
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/LoV5i3g6byeERHWo

Abs.

Comment: Valeu @Allan pela dica mais não é bem isso que estou tentando fazer, mas de qualquer maneira agradeço e vou tentando por aqui! Que agora além dessa dúvida surgiram outras, mas para que eu possa apreender tenho que sofrer, rsrsrsr

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi criar um exemplo, onde o agrupamento de informações é feito um filtro no `SELECT` com a propriedade `multiple`:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.operadora = [];
  $scope.operadoras = [{
      nome: "CLARO"
    },
    {
      nome: "TIM"
    },
    {
      nome: "VIVO"
    },
    {
      nome: "OI"
    },
    {
      nome: "NEXTEL"
    }
  ];

  $scope.lista = [{
      nome: 'item 1',
      operadora: 'OI'
    },
    {
      nome: 'item 2',
      operadora: 'OI'
    },
    {
      nome: 'item 3',
      operadora: 'CLARO'
    },
    {
      nome: 'item 4',
      operadora: 'NEXTEL'
    },
    {
      nome: 'item 5',
      operadora: 'VIVO'
    },
    {
      nome: 'item 6',
      operadora: 'TIM'
    }
  ];

  $scope.listFilter = function(model) {    
    if ($scope.operadora.length == 0) return true;
    return $scope.operadora.indexOf(model.operadora) > -1;
  };
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select multiple ng-model="operadora" class="selectpicker">
    <option ng-repeat="o in operadoras" value="{{o.nome}}">{{o.nome}}</option>
  </select>
  <br /><br /><br />
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in lista  | filter:listFilter">
      {{i.nome}} {{i.operadora}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Nesse caso [precisa criar um filtro customizado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/316140/54880), e buscar no `array` de informações os itens que foram selecionados no `SELECT` que é um outro `array` também.

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Filtrar data em formato pt-br no AngularJs?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/316106/filtrar-data-em-formato-pt-br-no-angularjs/316140#316140)
- [Filtro com angular em data com máscara 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/223664/filtro-com-angular-em-data-com-m%C3%A1scara-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss)
- [API Reference ng  filter components in ng  date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)
- [Angular Series: O filtro filter, ng-model, ng-repeat e algumas coisitas a mais …](https://medium.com/@hudsonbrendon/angular-series-o-filtro-filter-ng-model-ng-repeat-e-algumas-coisitas-mais-3f6a5630e9b9)
- [Série AngularJS – Usando Filter com search](https://imasters.com.br/front-end/serie-angularjs-usando-filter-com-search)